# How to restore default options for webdriver in selenium (using Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I tried to make edge in selenium work headless by settings --headless and --disable-gpu options, but now nothing works. Neither edge, nor chrome or firefox. Every time I encounter an error stating something like "Message: 'MicrosoftWebDriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH".

How do I fix this?

I tried adding the driver to my workspace but it did nothing. Also, the terminal gives a link to download the driver, but it does not work.

Comment: Dont use driver.exe, instead use WebDriverManager - refer: https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager   and   https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Comment: I tried it, but it also failed. I found a way to make Chrome work by manually downloading the driver and placing it in my C/Windows folder (no installation or path adjustment)

Comment: Post the code you've tried using WebDriverManager.